# How to Sort the Value of List by a Item in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have dataframe program like:

```
lst3 = [
        ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]],
        ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]],
        ['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]]
       ]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(lst3, columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price'], dtype = float) 
print(df3)
```

And the result is:

```
  store_name                    item                         price
0   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
1   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
2    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
```

The type of column 'item' and 'price' are list.

So, for example I wanna sort the dataframe by the lowest price of item 'acer'. The expected result is:

```
  store_name                    item                         price
2    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
0   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
1   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

[edit: additional] And, if sort the dataframe by the lowest price of item 'hp', the expected result is:

```
  store_name                    item                         price
0   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
2    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
```

Could you help me, how about the program script to make the result like above in Python?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to convert the `DataFrame` to records using `to_records()` method.

Sort it using python's builtin `sorted()` function.

Then convert back it to `DataFrame` using `from_records()`.

For your current `DataFrame` to sort price by minimum in the list, you can do following.

```
sorted_records = sorted(df3.to_records(), key=lambda x: min(x[3]))
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sorted_records)
```

Keep in track of the index of the column you are trying to sort from when converted to records.

[pd.DataFrame.to_records()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)

[pd.DataFrame.from_records()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the DataFrame does not contain an easy way to sort by specific-user-defined keys. so you can just create a translation to list and sort it as you wish like so:

```
def sort_by_product(df3, product):

    def get_product_price(current_store):
        current_product = product
        return current_store[2][current_store[1].index(current_product)]

    sorted_list = sorted(df3.values.tolist(), key=get_product_price)    
    return pd.DataFrame(sorted_list , columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price'], dtype = float)
```

usage example:

```
sort_by_product(df3, "acer")
```

Which outputs:

```
  store_name                    item                         price
0    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
1   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
2   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if all the list in column item contains the string **acer**

```
import pandas as pd

lst3 = [
        ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]],
        ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]],
        ['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]]
       ]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(lst3, columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price']) 

df3['new'] = df3['item'].apply(lambda x: x.index('acer'))

def f(x):
    return(x[2][x[3]])

df3['new']=df3.apply(f,axis=1)

df3.sort_values(by=['new'], inplace=True)

df3.drop(['new'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df3
```

The output is as follows:

```
    store_name                   item                         price
0      bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
1     it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
2     mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

I hope this does the work!

Answer (score 0):

**Question could be answered by using of RoundRobin algorithm.**

You could have more info on RoundRobin algorithm here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

"roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"

**I propose two coding styles for this purpose :**

**1/ STYLE 1**

- Creation of a round robin `rrobin` column containing elements in the form `[hp, 45000, acer, 15000, asus, 30000]` (item followed by its price)
- Creation of the `sortID` column containing the price of the selected item, in our case 'acer' which calculation is based upon the `rrobin` column

**Complete Code**

```py
import pandas as pd
from more_itertools import roundrobin as rb

lst3 = [
        ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]],
        ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]],
        ['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]]
       ]


df = pd.DataFrame(lst3, columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price'], dtype = float)
# Assign a round robin column
df = df.assign(rrobin=df.apply(lambda x: list(rb(x['item'], x['price'])), axis=1))
# Assign a sort ID column which is selected item price (in our case 'acer')
df = df.assign(sortID=df.apply(lambda x: x['rrobin'][x['rrobin'].index('acer')+1], axis=1))
# Sort and reduce df by suppressing useless columns
df.sort_values(by=['sortID'], inplace=True)
# Suppress useless columns
df.drop(columns=['rrobin', 'sortID'], inplace=True)

print(df)

#   store_name                    item                         price
# 2    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
# 0   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
# 1   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

**2/ STYLE 2**

First, let’s assume dataframe row is `['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]]`.
With the following code, Hardware is followed by price in the result :

```py
from more_itertools import roundrobin as rb
row = ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]]

round_robin = list(rb(row[1], row[2]))

print(round_robin)
# ['acer', 60000, 'dell', 75000]
```

Thus it’s possible to build a dict with shop as key-value and value as sort item price ie ‘ACER’ price in our case :

```py
import pandas as pd
from more_itertools import roundrobin as rb

lst3 = [
        ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]],
        ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]],
        ['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]]
       ]

d2 = {}
for k,v in {e[0] : list(rb(e[1], e[2])) for e in lst3}.items():
    try:
        d2[k]=v[v.index('acer')+1]
    except:
        continue
# d2 = {'it store': 30000, 'mz store': 60000, 'bm shop': 15000}
```

This is very important for us like the price of the item will serve to sorting like this :

```py
ord_lst3 = []
for shop in sorted(d2):
    ord_lst3 += list(filter(lambda e: e[0] == shop, lst3))

print(ord_lst3)

# [['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]], 
# ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]], 
# ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]]]
```

**Complete code :**

```py
import pandas as pd
from more_itertools import roundrobin as rb

lst3 = [
        ['it store', ['asus', 'acer', 'hp', 'dell'], [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]],
        ['mz store', ['acer', 'dell'], [60000, 75000]],
        ['bm shop', ['hp', 'acer', 'asus'], [45000, 15000, 30000]]
       ]

d2 = {}
for k,v in {e[0] : list(rb(e[1], e[2])) for e in lst3}.items():
    try:
        d2[k]=v[v.index('acer')+1]
    except:
        continue

ord_lst3 = []
for shop in sorted(d2):
    ord_lst3 += list(filter(lambda e: e[0] == shop, lst3))

df = pd.DataFrame(ord_lst3, columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price'], dtype = float) 
print(df)

#   store_name                    item                         price
# 0    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]
# 1   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
# 2   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary :

 `item` and `price` are related (`item` holds `acer`, the index of `acer` in `item` is directly related to its `price` in the `price` column). so we need to find a way to pair them.

 get the index of `acer` in `item` column, get its corresponding `price` in the `price` column, sort from smallest to biggest, get the indices, and use that index to reindex the dataframe:

```
from operator import itemgetter

#use enumerate to get the numbers attached
#we could also zip the index instead
sorter = sorted([(num,price[item.index('acer')]) 
                 for num, (item,price) 
                 in enumerate(zip(df3.item,df3.price))]
                ,key=itemgetter(1))

#extract only the first item from each tuple in the sorter list
new_index = [first for first,last in sorter]

#reindex dataframe to get our sorted form
df3.reindex(new_index)

       store_name         item                     price
2   bm shop     [hp, acer, asus]        [45000, 15000, 30000]
0   it store    [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]
1   mz store    [acer, dell]            [60000, 75000]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, [`Series.str.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.index.html) and [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
indexes = df3['item'].str.index('acer')

df = pd.DataFrame(df3['price'].tolist())

(df3.assign(acer_value = df.lookup(df.index , indexes))
    .sort_values('acer_value')
    .drop(columns='acer_value'))


  store_name                    item                         price  
2    bm shop        [hp, acer, asus]         [45000, 15000, 30000]  
0   it store  [asus, acer, hp, dell]  [50000, 30000, 20000, 10000]  
1   mz store            [acer, dell]                [60000, 75000]
```

Or:

```
order = (df3.assign(indexes = df3['item'].str.index('acer'))
            .apply(lambda x: x['price'][x['indexes']], axis=1)
            .sort_values().index)
df3.loc[order]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the DataFrame does not contain an easy way to sort by specific-user-defined keys. so you can just create a translation to list and sort it as you wish like so:

```py
def sort_by_product(df3, product):

    def get_product_price(current_store):
        current_product = product
        return current_store[2][current_store[1].index(current_product)]

    sorted_list = sorted(df3.values.tolist(), key=get_product_price)    
    return pd.DataFrame(sorted_list , columns =['store_name', 'item', 'price'], dtype = float)
```